# Proving that if $x$ is unit then $R\cong Rx$ (as rings) (Please check my proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

I want to prove this theorem. I have stuck in proving this theorem, in homomorphism axiom.

> Let $R$ be integral domain and $x\neq 0\in R$. Prove that if $x$ is
> unit then $R\cong Rx$ (as rings).

**Proof.**

Since $x$ is unit, there exist $y\in R$ such that $xy=1_R$ or $yx=1_R$. Let we construct the maps
$$
\begin{array}{l@{$\;$}c@{$\;$}c@{$\;$}c}
 f\colon & R &\to& Rx\\
 & r &\mapsto &rx.
\end{array}
$$

Take $a,b\in R$. We want to show $f$ is a ring homomorphism. Consider that
\begin{align*}
 f(a+b)&=(a+b)x\\
 &=ax+bx\\
 &= f(a)+f(b)
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 f(ab)&=(ab)x\\
\end{align*}
**(I'm stuck here, because I can't associate $x$ as unit with the axiom of homomorphism). How to prove it?**

Now we want to prove $f$ is onto and 1-1 maps.
For all $rx\in Rx$, there exist $r\in R$ such that $f(r)=rx$. So, $f$ is onto. Let $r_1,r_2\in R$. If $f(r_1)=f(r_2)$ then $r_1 x= r_2 x$. Since $R$ is integral domain, imply $r_1=r_2$. Thus, $f$ 1-1 maps.

**Does my proof for $f$ is onto and 1-1 maps is right?**

So, we (hope) can conclude $R\cong Rx$ (as rings).

Comment: Did you consider $x=-1$ for the ring $R=\mathbb Z$? It demonstrates that right multiplication by a unit is not always a ring homomorphism.  Honestly the question is quite silly when it asks for a homomorphism *of rings*. It makes much more sense for it to be homomorphism *of modules*.

Comment: Yes, according to your counter example, the maps $f(r)=rx$, where $x$ is unit, $f$ is not ring homomorphism. 
You say that right multiplication by a unit is not always a ring homomorphism. 
By the way, is there other maps $f:R\to Rx$ ($x$ is unit) such that $f$ is homomorphism?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the map $r \mapsto xr$ is not a homomorphism. This is because $x$ is a unit, but not $1_R$.

Still, $R \cong Rx$, but that's because actually $R = Rx$.